# What happened to my Python file?

Tags: python, corrupt-data

I've been working on creating a ray caster in Python, using Pygame, and I went back to work on it earlier today to find that it would not load properly. When I opened it, it appeared as if it were a new python document. I then tried to run it to see if that would make a difference, and it gave me the error:

[image: Error]

I have an older version of the file saved in the same directory too, and you can see that the apparently empty file still is a larger size than the one that still works. This suggests to me that the data is there, I just can't access it.

Is there a way to recover the data at all, and what can I do to stop this in the future?

[image: Files]

**EDIT:**

This is a screenshot showing what the file looks like once opened

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is suitable for stack overflow, and if it would be better suited to a different site please let me know and I'll move it.

Comment: This sounds like you might have changed the file's encoding accidentally.

Comment: Alternatively, you may have accidentally copy-pasted something weird into the file.

Comment: "When I opened it, it appeared as if it were a new python document." What did you use to open it? Try using something else to open it.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't remember doing anything like that, but how would I change it back to the normal encoding?

Comment: @Kevin The only application I use is Idle, what else can I use to open it?

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox it sounds like there is some hidden null character in the source script somewhere, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/qvOTS0Ma9Iw

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox: If you changed the encoding, you'd have to figure out what the new encoding is, open it in that encoding, and save it in the original encoding.

Comment: @downshift the entire document has disappeared, when I open it the file is empty but it still contains 10KB of data. I'll add a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Viewing the raw bytes, such as by opening the file in a hex editor or with Python in binary mode, may help you diagnose the problem. Also, important: **save a backup copy of the "corrupted" file now**, so if you accidentally screw things up further, you don't lose anything.

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox Try opening using sublime